# sum of division of two values, grouped, highest three

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I would like to get the highest three values from a table. The value is counted by adding together all 'volts' grouped by name and then dividing by amps. Amps is always the same for each name, so it does not need to be calculated (nor averaged).

I have tried the below example, but TotalSum returns 0 for all three.

```
SELECT name, sum(volts/amps) TotalSum 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_to)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY field1 
ORDER BY TotalSum 
LIMIT 3

...

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mostused, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'] . ' (' . $row['TotalSum'] . '), ';
}
```

Table:

```
name    volts    amps
A       10       2
A       15       2
A       12       2
B       2        1
B       4        1
B       8        1
C       20       5
C       20       5
C       20       5
```

Result sorted by highest:

```
1] A = 37/2 = 18.5 ... echo 'A (18.5)'
2] B = 14/1 = 14 ... echo 'B (14)'
3] C = 60/5 = 12 ... echo 'C (12)'
```

What's the mistake in my query?

Comment: DESC gets the highest. There is no field1. There is no time_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sort in descending order to get the highest three:

```
SELECT name, sum(volts/amps) TotalSum 
FROM mytable 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(time_to)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY TotalSum desc  -- here
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Very much appreciated!